# Starting app in debug mode starts the app then crashes after showing a white screen for a split second

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a blazor server application. Starting the app without debugging works fine but when I launch it in debug mode, it starts, goes through Program.cs then it open a white screen for split second and crashes. I'm not getting any error in the output, it says "The program 'localhost:5001' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)." in the end.

I have Windows 10 Home and Visual Studio 2022.

To make it even worse, another guy working on the same project has no problems at all. He can launch the app in debug mode without any problems. So I guess it should be a problem with my pc? But everything was fine yesterday and I don't remember changing anything.

I hope I explained everything clearly. Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Things I tried to do:

1. Restarted visual studio and my pc.
2. Rebuilt the solution.
3. Updated Visual Studio.
4. Deleted the bin and obj files and restarted.

The result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the debugger web browser from Chrome to Microsoft Edge. I have no idea why but it works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).